# Error with psql after installation of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, macos-sonoma

Used Homebrew to install Postgres@16 on Mac OS X Sonoma 14.3.1.

```
brew install postgresql@16
```

When I come to connect:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost

psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  auth_permission_dialog.dialog_executable_path is not a file
```

Answer (score 1):

After a reboot the error changed to:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I added a user:

```
createuser -s postgres
```

Restarted the service:

```
brew services restart postgresql@16
```

All good now:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
psql (16.2, server 16.1 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: The role `postgres` does not exist because Homebrew creates the cluster as owned by the OS user you installed as. That means the command to connect can be simplified to `psql postgres` when run as that OS user.  See [Homebrew](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew), also [How to install Homebrew](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/installing-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew/)

Answer (score 0):

after the installation with homebrew, there is one user in Postgres (named like your login-Name e.g."YourUsername").
And there is one database with name "postgres". 
Lokk at the result of

```
psql --help
```

you will see what the problem is?

```
Usage:
   psql [OPTION]... [DBNAME [USERNAME]]

General options:
...

-U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "YourUsername")
-d, --dbname=DBNAME      database name to connect to (default: "YourUsername")

...
```

For your first access you should simply call.

```
psql postgres    or    psql -d postgres
```

The second parameter is just the database-name and therefore the result is something like this.

```
postgres=#
```

Now you can do, whatever you want. Feel free to create a database with name "YourUsername".

```
create database YourUsername;
```

with the result:

```
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=#
```

Leave the cli and call psql without any Parameter.

```
postgres=# \q

-->
psql

psql (14.11 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.

YourUsername=#
```

What happend? Postgres found the default user and the default database. You can see you are working on the database YourUsername, since the result shows
YourUsername=#.

Its quite easy.